# How to SSH to a remote server using a private key on Linux?

Tags: ssh, putty, private-key

I have been trying to connect to a remote server using my private key file from the terminal, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't understand why. Here is how I do it:

```
$ ssh -i private.ppk oap@10.20.0.11
Enter passphrase for key 'private.ppk':
Enter passphrase for key 'private.ppk':
Enter passphrase for key 'private.ppk':
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

My private key file has 600 mode. I am able to use [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) on my Linux box to connect with this private key file. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a putty key. It will not work with *nix `ssh` clients. You need to use `PuTTYgen` or similar software in order to convert your key to openssh format.

Answer (score 8):

`openssh` and `PuTTY` are using different key types (but you can convert between them). In PuTTYgen you need to go to `Conversions->Export OpenSSH`, export your private key and store it as `id_rsa`.

More on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2224204/2196426) or [SU](https://superuser.com/a/1033757/466930).